# Browsers are very slow

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, google-chrome, browser

I am using WiFi on a MacBook Pro with 8GB of RAM.

When I test the speed using Speedtest.net or Fast.com I get around 20MBps down and 10MBps up.

When I am actually browsing, pages require anywhere from a few seconds to many minutes to load (sometimes completely failing or loading only partially and stopping). I find myself often jumping between several tabs that have all been loading for many minutes.

What can I test to figure out where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to rule out is bufferbloat. It's a bug in a lot of routers and modems that causes them to increase latency (lagginess) during congestion, instead of letting TCP congestion control work properly.

During a time when browsers seem slow, run [dslreports.com/speedtest](http://dslreports.com/speedtest) and see what your latency is in milliseconds (and your latency grade).

If it's not bufferbloat, I'd look at things like DNS latency (use a tool like `dig` to run some DNS lookups and see how long it takes to get responses) and latency to the local edge nodes of well-known CDNs (use a tool like `nettop` to see the RTT to various IP addresses your browser is connecting to). I suppose I'd look for the possibility of high packet loss as well (run ping for 100 seconds to an external IP address and see what percentage are dropped), but I would think that high packet loss would have killed your throughput as well, so it seems less likely.

Also make sure you're not accidentally configured to use some VPN or proxy you'd forgotten about. If all your traffic is going through a slow VPN or proxy, that could be your problem.

Comment: First thing I'd do before any of those tests is *"switch it off then back on again"*. Trite as it sounds, it's often the 'miracle cure' for domestic routers; lets them get their pea-brained thoughts back in order ;)